# How to register binary XML schema (using Oracle12c)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a problem with registering BINARY XML schema using Oracle 12c version.

If I'm correct BINARY scheme registration option is available since Oracle 11g version? But using 12c it shows me an error that BINARY option is still not declared.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA
        (
         SCHEMAURL => 'http://localhost:8080/public/leagues.xsd',
         SCHEMADOC =>  bfilename('XMLDIR', 'LEAGUES.xsd'),
         GENTYPES  =>  FALSE,
         OPTIONS   =>  REGISTER_BINARYXML 
        );
END;
/
```

As a result of this, I receive an error :

`PLS-00201: identifier 'REGISTER_BINARYXML' must be declared`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Because that option (`register_binaryxml`) should be invoked through `dbms_xmlschema` package as `dbms_xmlschema.register_binaryxml`.*

*That is, replace `options => register_binaryxml` with `options => dbms_xmlschema.register_binaryxml`*